# Html Agility Pack - Select Divs inside Div

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

fairly new to the HTML Agility Pack. I've been searching and trying many examples but didn't get to a conclusion yet.. must be doing something wrong.. hope you can assist me.

My goal is to parse the latest news from a website, including image, title and date - pretty simple. I managed to get the image (background attribute) from the div but the divs are nested and for some reason I can't access their values. Here is my code

```
using System;
using HtmlAgilityPack;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var html = @"https://pristontale.eu/";
        HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
        var doc = web.Load(html);
        
        var news = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[contains(@class,'index-article-wrapper')]");
        
        foreach (var item in news){
            var image = Regex.Match(item.GetAttributeValue("style", ""), @"(?<=url\()(.*)(?=\))").Groups[1].Value;
            var title = item.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='article-title']").InnerText;
            var date = item.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='article-date']").InnerText;
            Console.WriteLine(image, title, date);
            
        }
    }
}
```

This is what the HTML looks like

```
<div class="index-article-wrapper" onclick="location.href='article.php?id=2';" style="background-image: url(https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/765749063621935104/884439050562461696/1_1.png)">
    <div class="meta-wrapper">
        div class="article-date">5 Sep, 2021</div>
        <div class="article-title">Server merge v1.264 update</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Currently it correctly grabs me all the 4 news articles but only the image - how do i get title and date of each? I have a fiddle here https://dotnetfiddle.net/BVcAmH

Appreciate the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just realized the code has been correct all along, the only flaw was the `Console.WriteLine`

Wrong

```
Console.WriteLine(image, title, date);
```

Correct

```
Console.WriteLine(image + " " + " " + title + " " + date);
```